# SendKeys.Send skips random letters

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm facing a problem of which I can't find info/solutions on Google.

In VB 2010 I'm using these simple lines of code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Shell("cmd.exe /k cd C:\Program Files (x86)/MKVToolNix")
        SendKeys.Send("mkvextract.exe tracks J:\Movies\Bait.mkv 2:J:\Movies\Bait.srt {ENTER} ")
End Sub
```

Most of the times it skips random letters, for example the first `m` (`mkvextract.exe`) or the `:` in `J:\Movies` or some letters in the file or folder name... It's pretty weird and annoying. How can I fix this?

Art

Comment: Have you tried surrounding the text with quotes? This works when dealing with command prompt and paths including spaces.

Comment: @varocarbas You mean also use single quotes?

Comment: No. Double quotes. For example: `SendKeys.Send("""" & "this string is quoted" & """")`. You have to escape them (2x each + opening/closing quote), that is, writing a single double quote alone, as in the example above, is represented with 4 quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if it will work this way instead:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim p As New Process
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MKVToolNix\mkvextract.exe"
    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MKVToolNix"
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "tracks J:\Movies\Bait.mkv 2:J:\Movies\Bait.srt"
    p.Start()
End Sub
```